# `[AnyObject]` to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, spotify

Facing issue while casting `[AnyObject]` to `NSMutableArray`.
trying to convert below code to swift2.0

```
 NSString *search = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    [[SpotifySDKAPI sharedInstance]searchSPTracks:self.session searchQuery:search completionHandler:^(SPTListPage *trackList, NSString *error) {
        NSArray* tempArray = trackList.items;
        self.spotifySearchResults = [tempArray mutableCopy];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
```

[image]

Comment: just replace this code self.searchResults = (tempArray as! NSMutableArray).mutableCopy

Comment: not working man@SaurabhPrajapati

Comment: Is this an objective-c question or a swift question? Why do you have both tags?

Comment: i had provided obj-c code and having problem while converting.@AlbertRenshaw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Swift array **CANNOT** be cast to an `NSMutableArray` however for all intents and purposes a Swift array and `NSArray` are completely interchangeable. If you want to init an `NSMutableArray` all you have to do is:

`var mutableArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: swiftArray)`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare [AnyObject] as VAR instead LET and can append objects to it and it will be mutable object. No need to convert [AnyObject] to NSMutableArray if thats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following answer

```
     let search: String = searchBar.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "%20")
     SpotifySDKAPI.sharedInstance().searchSPTracks(self.session, searchQuery: search, completionHandler: {(trackList: SPTListPage, error: String) -> Void in
       var tempArray: [AnyObject] = trackList.items
       self.spotifySearchResults = tempArray.mutableCopy()
       self.tableView.reloadData()
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing below line with replacing `AnyObject` to `NSMutableArray`:-

```
let tempArray : NSMutableArray = trackList.items
```